# Electron-builder(electron notarize) - No suitable image -MacOS

Tags: macos, electron-builder, robotjs, electron-notarize

I am using iohook module, in the local build its working fine ,For production build distribution after Mac notarize it's not working its saying *no suitable image found*
any solution, please
[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSzHt.png)

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots of error messages: include the actual error text instead.

Comment: I agree with Smitop. It is likely that the link to your screenshot will not work in the future so that people who are searching on this problem down the road won't have all of the information. You need to copy the error message text and paste it into your post and then highlight it and select the code format { } so that it's formatted correctly.